# Get Schedule for the current day or first coming up

Tags: mysql, where

I am building a scheduling app, where I assign schedules to certain members but those schedules can change at a certain date or be assigned for the future.

My database structure is like so:

```
members table:
------------------------------------
member_id


schedule table:
------------------------------------
schedule_id
schedule_name

assigned_schedules asch table:
------------------------------------
member_id
schedule_id
effective_from
effective_to
```

The `effective_to` and `effective_from` values are a unix timestamp. I currently have joined the tables but my where clause is quite redundant and has errors in it. I am looking to get the schedule currently assigned for the current day of a member, or the closest assigned schedule if there is one assigned in the future. A member can have a schedule assigned to a future date and it would change at that time, but I am looking for a daily view.

Currently, I join all the tables and have this where clause (where the `?` is today's timestamp):

`( asch.effective_from  <= ? AND ( asch.effective_to IS NULL OR asch.effective_to >= ? ) OR asch.effective_from IS NULL ) 
XOR 
( ( asch.effective_from > ? AND asch.effective_to IS NULL ) XOR asch.effective_from > ?  )`

`assigned_to` value can be null, which means that the schedule has no termination time.

Comment: Is effective_from always before asch.effective_to? That would simplify the query.

Comment: @KenKim what do you mean by before? It does not have to be, no. I just need a way to get one record for each member, really.